# How do I submit tickets to a Kayako Resolve API from within PHP after reading emails with POP3?

Tags: php, api, pop3

***UPDATED: Please read the answer(s) to this question before posting a new one! Thanks.***

This is for work. (I work at Acenet, Inc - a webhost - so my code will be sanitized of vital logins & other API data). I need some help with a script I am writing:

```
<?php
/* lothbrok.php - abuse notification email-reader & ticket-injector script for Acenet Inc */

/*
 * 
 * "One script to rule them all,
 * One script to find them.
 * One script to bring them home,
 * And in the darkness, bind them."
 * 
 */

if ($_GET['worms'] != "food") {
    echo "Sorry, but you are not authorized to run LOTHBROK today! Goodbye!";
    exit;
} else {
require("email_functions.php");


global $timeout, $error, $buffer;

// Date in the past
header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");

// always modified
header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");

// HTTP/1.1
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);

// HTTP/1.0
header("Pragma: no-cache");

ob_start();

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
//                 Declarations
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

$error              = "";                       //    Error string.

$timeout            = 90;                       //    Default timeout before giving up on a network operation.

$Count              = -1;                       //    Mailbox msg count

$buffer             = 512;                      //    Socket buffer for socket fgets() calls, max per RFC 1939 the returned line a POP3 server can send is 512 bytes.

$server             = "SANITIZED";      //    Set this to hard code the server name

$RFC1939            = false;                    //    Set by noop(). See rfc1939.txt

$msg_list_array     = array();                  //    List of messages from server

$login              = 'SANITIZED';
$pass               = 'SANITIZED';

 //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 //                 The Code
 //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    echo "<h1>LOTHBROK</h1><h2>Starting Program</h2><br>";
         set_time_limit($timeout);

         $fp = connect ($server, $port = 110);

    $Count = login($login,$pass, $fp);

    if( (!$Count) or ($Count == -1) )
    {
         exit;
  }// end if
  if ($Count < 1)
  {
      die();
  } else {
      echo "Login OK: Inbox contains [$Count] messages<BR>\n";
      $msg_list_array = uidl("", $fp);
      set_time_limit($timeout);
   }// end if

    // loop thru the array to get each message
   for ($i=1; $i <= $Count; $i++){
        set_time_limit($timeout);
        $MsgOne = top($i, empty($numLines), $fp);

        if( (!$MsgOne) or (gettype($MsgOne) != "array") )
        {
            echo "oops, Message not returned by the server.<BR>\n";
            exit;
        }// end if
        /*
            call the function to read the message
            returns true if access, breakdown and insertion
            in to db are completed sucessfully
       */
       /*
        Function to read the message and extract :
            a. subject
            b. date
            c. split the body line by line
    */
       $body            = '';       // get the body of the message into 1 variable
       $subjects        = '';       // get the subject of the email
       $dates           = '';       // get the date of the email
       $body_start_key  = false;    // body starts at blank line, blank line is separator for from headers to body
       $TIRSFlag        = false;    // flag for seeing if the email is really to be processed by the app
       $base64Flag      = false;    // flag to handle base 64 encoding by email systems.



        foreach ($MsgOne as $key => $value)
    {
    if (trim($value) == "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64"){
      $base64Flag = true;
    }//end if

    //get the subject line of the email
    preg_match("/^(Subject\:) (.*)\r?\n$/i",$subjects,$subject);

      //look for "FBL" in the subject to see if we need to attempt to process the email
      if (strstr($subject,"FBL")) {
          $TIRSFlag = true;
        }// end if
    }// end if

    //get the date of the email
    preg_match("/(Date\:) ^([A-Za-z]{3}), ([0-9]{2}) ([A-Za-z]{3}) ([0-9]{4}) ([0-9]{2})\:([0-9]{2})\:([0-9]{2}) \-?([0-9]{4})$\r?\n/i",$subjects,$dates);

    // Grab the message body
        $MsgOne = get($i, $fp);

    //the body
    if (strlen(trim($value))==0){
      if ($body_start_key == false){ $body_start_key = true; } //set the start key for the body
    }//end if

    if ($body_start_key == true){
      $body .= trim($value);
      if ($base64Flag == false){ $body .="<br />"; }
    }// end if

  }// end foreach

  // only create support ticket(s) if the subject line contains the acronym "FBL"
  if ($TIRSFlag == false){
        echo "<br>Nothing to read - finished.</b>";
        exit;
  }else{

      //decode the message if its base64 encoded
      if ($base64Flag == true) {
        $body = base64_decode($body);
      } //end if

  } 
         //convert the body crlf to <br> tags if not done when the message was built
         $body = nl2br($body);
         $body = preg_replace("/^(Please investigate these FBL reports accordingly and create a ticket for the client if need be.)$/i"," ",$body);
         $body = preg_replace("/^(Acenet) (AOL|Comcast|Yahoo!?|Hotmail) (FBL Bot)$/i"," ",$body);
 /* Cordoned off in case something doesn't work and this is then neeeded.....
            $dayn = substr($date,0,2);
            $day = substr($date,6,7);
            $monn = substr($date,9,11);
            $monn = substr($date,9,11);
            $year = substr($date,13,16);
            $fhrd = substr($date,18,19);
            $mind = substr($date,20,21);
            $secd = substr($date,22,23);
            $msed = substr($date,26,30);
 End of Quarantine! :D .... */
         while (preg_match("/(THIS IS AN AUTOMATED ABUSE ALERT - DO NOT REPLY)/i",$body) && $dates > strtotime($dates - 8)) {

        // Here goes the part to actually make things work!

 /* Yet another Quarantine section....
        preg_match("/^\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\z/", $subject, $ipaddy);   // Client's first name in records (check WHMCS)
        preg_match("/^(AOL|Hotmail|Yahoo|Comcast|Facebook|Google|Gmail)$/", $subject, $mailnet);    // FBL Reporting Mailsys Network (Hotmail, Comcast, Yahoo!, Google, or AOL)
 Hello, back to the news! */

        $getArray["e"] = "/Tickets/Ticket";
        $apiUrl = "SANITIZED" . $getArray["e"];
        $apiKey = "SANITIZED";
        $salt =  mt_rand(1,99);
        $secretKey = "SANITIZED";
        $signature = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha256',$salt,$secretKey,true));

        $subject = "Abuse Email Ticket (TESTING - DO NOT RESPOND!)";
        $fullname = "Ragnar Lothbrok";
        $email = "burningjunk@mailinator.com";
        $contents = "Hello anonymous Acenet user,\n\nWe have recently received an FBL (Feedback Loop) Report from an email provider indicating users have identified one or more messages originating from your account as spam. \n\nAcenet is setup to receive a notification any time email sent from our network arrives in the mailbox of another user at this provider and that email provider's user clicks \"This is Spam\" for that email. This is known as a Feedback Loop, we receive Feedback from external mail providers categorizing email which is sent from our network.\n\nThere are many reasons other users may be categorizing mail from your account as spam. The purpose of this notification is not to imply you are a spammer, but to factually inform you that a user has clicked \"This is Spam\" for email sent from your account. \n\nAlong with the FBL, we receive details about the email itself including the Sender, Subject, and Header information. Please note that the exact recipient of the email is often removed by the mail provider as part of their privacy policy. You will often see <redacted> in place of the true recipient's email address.\n\nThe relevant information related to this FBL Report is included below. \n\nIt's important to understand that we are not implying you are a spammer. But, it is our goal to assist you in determining why this report was generated for your emails. If these reports continue to generate, the aforementioned email provider may end up blacklisting your IP and prevent you from emailing those users. By working with our Technicians to address these FBL reports, we can help you to avoid such a situation.\n\nIf the email details provided below are unfamiliar to you, please update this ticket and our Technicians will be happy to review the contents and help interpret how this email may have originated from your account.\n\n\nIf you recognize the email details provided, you should review your mailing practices and attempt to identify why recipients are clicking \"This is Spam\" for these emails.\nFBL Reporting Information follows:\n-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n$body\n\n\n";
        $departmentid = "9";
        $ticketstatusid = "4";
        $ticketpriorityid = "9";
        $tickettypeid = "1";
        $staffid = "27";

        $post_data = array('subject' => $subject,
            'fullname' => $fullname,
            'email' => $email,
            'contents' => $contents,
            'departmentid' => $departmentid,
            'ticketstatusid' => $ticketstatusid,
            'ticketpriorityid' => $ticketpriorityid,
            'tickettypeid' => $tickettypeid,
            'staffid' => $staffid, 
            'apikey' => $apiKey, 
            'salt' => $salt, 
            'signature' => $signature);

        $post_data = http_build_query($post_data, '', '&');

        $curl = curl_init($apiUrl); 
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $apiUrl);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, true); 
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);

        $response = curl_exec($curl);  
        curl_close($curl);


       }// end for loop



    //close the email box and delete all messages marked for deletion
    quit($fp);

    //close the application
    echo "<br>Finished</b>";
    exit;

    }
  /* Have a nice day! */

  ?>
```

Anyway, my issue is that I need to read only the previous 7 days' worth (in other words: a week's worth) of abuse email messages and submit them as support tickets within our firm's Kayako installation. The Kayako API I have down pat; the problem for me is how do I **ONLY** read the last week's worth of abuse notices and **NOT** all the notices in the entire email account (last 2 times I ran this script, it kept on going and going and going like the Energizer Bunny and I had to run a **kill -9 [process ID]** command on the server where the script & its process were located).

By the way, as for the "email-functions.php" script this script mentions: ignore it. It was written by other folks, not me, so I can't vouch for its erroneousness.

*I can only admit to the faults in my own coding...*

If anyone knows how to fix my issue, please leave a reply or comment, thank you!

Comment: Sorry if this sounds a tad pushy, but my boss expects me to get this project done by this coming Wednesday... which is why I am asking this question here.

Comment: The original code (in two major parts + some minor ones) were gotten from various locations on the Internet. I made heavy modifications to fit our firm's needs.

Comment: FYI in case anyone mentions IMAP via PHP: Our server runs PHP 5.2.17, which to the best of my knowledge does not support IMAP via PHP.

Comment: [`imap_open`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imap-open.php) - `(PHP 4, PHP 5)`

Comment: why thank you - I did not know that! However, I don't feel like rewriting the entire script to patch in an IMAP function when I've been succesfully using POP3 to read the emails for a week now. I have no issues accessing emails; my issue is with the preg_match thing and trying to get only the past 7 days' worth of messages rather than everything since the 1st day of the Lord's Creation...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Easy answer:**

What I am doing is pointless. The way my firm handles the tickets that come in on abuse (actually, submits abuse tickets based on email notices) needs fixing before any of these PHP/Kayako REST API scripts become handy.

**The Long Answer:**

Our firm currently processes all abuse notices and submits them to the Kayako ticketing support system using human beings as the transfer method. However, our human-powered ticket submission (and client look-up using WHMCS) is flawed in that only humans could use it; were we to try to integrate (or automate) a robotic (automated) system into our current methods, it would, as Bill Gates (or someone else) once famously said, "magnify the inefficiencies" in our own current system methodology.

Therefore, I have decided the script is a farce. It's not worth it; I plan to inform my boss of this by midnight tomorrow morning, and also present him with a plan to fix the current system. In the meantime I will be writing that business plan.

Comment: *"With that said, moderators: please close this question thread. Thanks."* you should accept your answer, we don't close questions for this reason.

Comment: How do I accept my own answer? Is it legal to do so (i.e. won't get me banned)? @WouterJ please respond, thanks.

Comment: I click the checkmark but it says I have to wait until manana.

Comment: it legal to accept your own answer, it's the best practise in this case. And yes, you need to wait 48 hours :)